# How to use NVDA screen reader in winForm application c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am working in winform application [Not WPF]. I need to support NVDA screen reader. Can anyone help how to make my application to support NVDA?

Does NVDA provide any SDK to used with .net ?

How can I implement below function in NVDA for Anouncing button name as i do with default narrator?

```
private void btnLogon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using(SpeechSynthesizer synth =new SpeechSynthesizer()) {
    synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    synth.Speak("You have Pressed LOGON Button");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used ScreenReaderAPI from Nuget package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used screenreaderapi and used saystring method.